# symbol λ doesn´t work in jar file but in eclipse run yes

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, spring-boot, lambda

I do not have any problem while I am in Eclipse, but when I run a the jar file, problems apperars.

This are the different exists that produce the program.
    Eclipse

```
   Clave: B := CB| b| S| 
   Clave: S := aBCd|  -> axioma
   Clave: C := cc| e| λ|
```

Jar
      [Exit from Jar file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/33AIx.png)
I can´t write because have special characters

The problem is that the jar file doesn´t write λ in the variable of the program, so when i want to use the program crash.

This is in a Spring Application.

Thanks

Comment: The specials characters are the problem

Comment: [I downvoted because without code, it is very hard to help you](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/). Where does the `λ` character come from? How is it printed?

Comment: Is this console output? Or a website? It is likely that it is an encoding problem.

Comment: If you run the JAR on the command line on Windows, does executing `chcp 65001` before `java ...` fix your problem?

Comment: @Andreas This is an encoding problem, I don't think the source code is relevant here. If the character is written by the JAR, it is probably hardcoded, right?

Comment: @howlger *"probably hardcoded"*? Sure, we can *guess*, or, you know, write a comment asking for clarification, which is what I did. Just because the character is printed by code in a jar file, doesn't mean the *text* being printed is hard-coded in the jar file. Question doesn't say anything about what the code is doing, but it's far more likely that the printed values are the result of processing of some input, and reading input is 50% of where encoding issues occur (writing output being the other 50%).

Comment: @howlger More importantly, being an encoding issue, that OP wants help with, we'd need to see the code where the encoding error occurs, so we can suggest fixes to the code. As such, source code is very relevant here. All depending on my first question: Where does the `λ` character come from?

Comment: @Andreas It is about running bytecode which itself is independent of the encoding. What difference would it make if the character were calculated, read from a file or via HTTP received? Can you give a code example that results in different outputs (Eclipse vs. JAR) due to a coding error?

Comment: @howlger Sure, e.g. reading a UTF-8 encoded file using ISO-8859-1 encoding. `λ` is encoded in UTF-8 as bytes `CE BB`, which in ISO-8859-1 is `Î»`, exactly as displayed in the image in the question. If the code doesn't correctly specify the encoding, and relies sorely of defaults, the result may change depending on how the code is run. --- Or, if the code is hardcoded to print in UTF-8, Eclipse console was configured to print UTF-8, but Windows command prompt prints Windows-1252 by default, the result is also what we see. --- **The code matters**, e.g. to see if encoding is hardcoded.

Comment: @Andreas Reading the same file with a specific encoding results in each case (when running from within Eclipse and when running the JAR) to the same output. The question is not how, but where the character is printed. Even if the source code for the JAR was compiled via Maven or Gradle with the wrong encoding, it wouldn't be helpful to know the Java code.

Comment: @howlger It would *if* the character was a string literal, in which case the wrong encoding when *compiling* the file would be the cause, e.g. Eclipse compiled (UTF-8, good) vs build script compiled (ISO-8859-1, bad). Without knowing **where** the string is coming from, *and* how the code is **handling** the string (input/output), we cannot identify the part of the the process that is causing the issue.

Comment: @Andreas So you don't give a code example that leads to different outputs in both cases? What was the reason why you voted that question down?

Comment: @howlger If you read the article linked by my first comment, you'd know the reason, but let be quote some of it for you: *"Why this is worth a downvote? Without the code, the question is not answerable. Any solution would be based on guesses. Even if someone guessed right, not having any code means it’s harder to relate for future readers. Questions that aren’t useful for people other than the asker are discouraged on Stack Overflow."* --- The down-vote will be removed once the quality of the question has been improved (assuming I'm notified of it).

Comment: @Andreas So you don't give a code example that leads to different outputs in both cases?

Comment: @howlger Sure: `System.out.println("λ");`. If run in Eclipse, with Eclipse Console configured for UTF-8, it prints `λ`. If run in Windows command prompt, it will print something else. --- But that is just one *example* and may not be OPs problem. We can't know that actual problem without more information, so that's what [I asked for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52043761/symbol-%ce%bb-doesn%c2%b4t-work-in-jar-file-but-in-eclipse-run-yes?noredirect=1#comment91038429_52043761). Right now, *the question is not answerable*.

Comment: @Andreas Your code example generates the same output in both cases. The code example does not tell where (e.g. on Windows, on Linux, redirected by a logger to somewhere, etc.) and with which encoding the output is displayed to the user. You justified your downvote with a link to a controversial, external site that talks about _"doesn’t include any of the buggy code"_. I asked you for an example of such a buggy code, asking for code as you did.

Comment: Hi,  I solve it. The problem as you said was the encoding, but not when i write the symbol. The problem was that the inputReader that i use before, read wrong the character i have to force it to with a parameter to read whith UTF-8 and not with the input use by default in JARs file.  The difference between Eclipse and JAR is that I had eclipse configure with UTF-8 by default. Thanks for all

Comment: I take into account what @Andreas about the code. I thought that in this case will be more tecnical or theory problem than no code problem, something like configurations or something like that. But now i am with the  mobile and i can not write code but when i switch on the computer i put the lines of code that works. For helpping other people.

Comment: @howlger As you can see from latest comments, it is the **code**, i.e. the `Reader`, used to read the text that was the culprit. So, referring back to your first comment saying *"I don't think the source code is relevant here"*, the code was definitely **relevant**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an **encoding problem**: e. g. **`λ`** encoded in **UTF-8** will be shown as **`Î»`** when using the **ISO-8859-16** encoding.

Because strings are stored as UTF-8 in Java bytecode, the encoding error could occur either during compilation or when printing:

- If you are **not using Eclipse to create the JAR** but e.g. Maven or Gradle, make sure to use the **correct encoding** for the source code in the **compile** task (see [here for Maven](https://maven.apache.org/general.html#encoding-warning) and [here for Gradle](http://blog.ehrnhoefer.com/2015-02-28-gradle-sourcefile-encoding/))
- When **output**ting, make sure that where **UFT-8** is printed, this is correctly **decoded as UTF-8**. This depends on where `λ` is printed (e. g. on the Windows command prompt, on a Linux terminal or into an HTML file). **In Eclipse the encoding** for the ***Console*** view is set in the **run configuration** in the tab ***Common***.

Answer (score 0):

In this case the solution exactly was:

**BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(isFile, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));**

De ese mmodo obligas a que lea por defecto en UTF_8 y no dependas del resto de configuraciones